# Oracle virtualbox not allowing than one CPU - Hardware virtualization not available

Tags: virtualbox, virtualization, hardware-virtualization, amd-phenom

I have the following hardware configuration:

- Processor: AMD FX-8120 (Zambezi)
- Board: ASUS M5A88-M
- OS : Windows 8.1
- RAM : 4GB DDR3

I installed Genymotion which created a virtual machine for Android. However, whenever I try to start the machine, it shows that only one CPU can be used as hardware virtualization is not available.

Here is the screenshot of Virtualbox

[image: Hardware visualization not available]

I think that hardware virtualization is supported with this CPU and Board. Is there any setting which I've missed?

How can I make VirtualBox use more CPU?

## Update:

Here is the output of coreinfo

```
AMD FX(tm)-8120 Eight-Core Processor           
AMD64 Family 21 Model 1 Stepping 2, AuthenticAMD
Microcode signature: 06000629
HTT         *   Multicore
HYPERVISOR  *   Hypervisor is present
VMX         -   Supports Intel hardware-assisted virtualization
SVM         -   Supports AMD hardware-assisted virtualization
X64         *   Supports 64-bit mode

SMX         -   Supports Intel trusted execution
SKINIT      -   Supports AMD SKINIT

NX          *   Supports no-execute page protection
SMEP        -   Supports Supervisor Mode Execution Prevention
SMAP        -   Supports Supervisor Mode Access Prevention
PAGE1GB     -   Supports 1 GB large pages
PAE         *   Supports > 32-bit physical addresses
PAT         *   Supports Page Attribute Table
PSE         *   Supports 4 MB pages
PSE36       *   Supports > 32-bit address 4 MB pages
PGE         *   Supports global bit in page tables
SS          -   Supports bus snooping for cache operations
VME         *   Supports Virtual-8086 mode
RDWRFSGSBASE    -   Supports direct GS/FS base access

FPU         *   Implements i387 floating point instructions
MMX         *   Supports MMX instruction set
MMXEXT      *   Implements AMD MMX extensions
3DNOW       -   Supports 3DNow! instructions
3DNOWEXT    -   Supports 3DNow! extension instructions
SSE         *   Supports Streaming SIMD Extensions
SSE2        *   Supports Streaming SIMD Extensions 2
SSE3        *   Supports Streaming SIMD Extensions 3
SSSE3       *   Supports Supplemental SIMD Extensions 3
SSE4a       *   Supports Streaming SIMDR Extensions 4a
SSE4.1      *   Supports Streaming SIMD Extensions 4.1
SSE4.2      *   Supports Streaming SIMD Extensions 4.2

AES         *   Supports AES extensions
AVX         *   Supports AVX intruction extensions
FMA         -   Supports FMA extensions using YMM state
MSR         *   Implements RDMSR/WRMSR instructions
MTRR        *   Supports Memory Type Range Registers
XSAVE       *   Supports XSAVE/XRSTOR instructions
OSXSAVE     *   Supports XSETBV/XGETBV instructions
RDRAND      -   Supports RDRAND instruction
RDSEED      -   Supports RDSEED instruction

CMOV        *   Supports CMOVcc instruction
CLFSH       *   Supports CLFLUSH instruction
CX8         *   Supports compare and exchange 8-byte instructions
CX16        *   Supports CMPXCHG16B instruction
BMI1        -   Supports bit manipulation extensions 1
BMI2        -   Supports bit manipulation extensions 2
ADX         -   Supports ADCX/ADOX instructions
DCA         -   Supports prefetch from memory-mapped device
F16C        -   Supports half-precision instruction
FXSR        *   Supports FXSAVE/FXSTOR instructions
FFXSR       *   Supports optimized FXSAVE/FSRSTOR instruction
MONITOR     -   Supports MONITOR and MWAIT instructions
MOVBE       -   Supports MOVBE instruction
ERMSB       -   Supports Enhanced REP MOVSB/STOSB
PCLMULDQ    *   Supports PCLMULDQ instruction
POPCNT      *   Supports POPCNT instruction
LZCNT       *   Supports LZCNT instruction
SEP         *   Supports fast system call instructions
LAHF-SAHF   *   Supports LAHF/SAHF instructions in 64-bit mode
HLE         -   Supports Hardware Lock Elision instructions
RTM         -   Supports Restricted Transactional Memory instructions

DE          *   Supports I/O breakpoints including CR4.DE
DTES64      -   Can write history of 64-bit branch addresses
DS          -   Implements memory-resident debug buffer
DS-CPL      -   Supports Debug Store feature with CPL
PCID        -   Supports PCIDs and settable CR4.PCIDE
INVPCID     -   Supports INVPCID instruction
PDCM        -   Supports Performance Capabilities MSR
RDTSCP      *   Supports RDTSCP instruction
TSC         *   Supports RDTSC instruction
TSC-DEADLINE    -   Local APIC supports one-shot deadline timer
TSC-INVARIANT   *   TSC runs at constant rate
xTPR        -   Supports disabling task priority messages

EIST        -   Supports Enhanced Intel Speedstep
ACPI        -   Implements MSR for power management
TM          -   Implements thermal monitor circuitry
TM2         -   Implements Thermal Monitor 2 control
APIC        *   Implements software-accessible local APIC
x2APIC      -   Supports x2APIC

CNXT-ID     -   L1 data cache mode adaptive or BIOS

MCE         *   Supports Machine Check, INT18 and CR4.MCE
MCA         *   Implements Machine Check Architecture
PBE         -   Supports use of FERR#/PBE# pin

PSN         -   Implements 96-bit processor serial number

PREFETCHW   *   Supports PREFETCHW instruction

Maximum implemented CPUID leaves: 0000000D (Basic), 8000001E (Extended).

Logical to Physical Processor Map:
**------  Physical Processor 0 (Hyperthreaded)
--**----  Physical Processor 1 (Hyperthreaded)
----**--  Physical Processor 2 (Hyperthreaded)
------**  Physical Processor 3 (Hyperthreaded)

Logical Processor to Socket Map:
********  Socket 0

Logical Processor to NUMA Node Map:
********  NUMA Node 0

No NUMA nodes.

Logical Processor to Cache Map:
*-------  Data Cache          0, Level 1,   16 KB, Assoc   4, LineSize  64
**------  Instruction Cache   0, Level 1,   64 KB, Assoc   2, LineSize  64
**------  Unified Cache       0, Level 2,    2 MB, Assoc  16, LineSize  64
********  Unified Cache       1, Level 3,    8 MB, Assoc  64, LineSize  64
-*------  Data Cache          1, Level 1,   16 KB, Assoc   4, LineSize  64
--*-----  Data Cache          2, Level 1,   16 KB, Assoc   4, LineSize  64
--**----  Instruction Cache   1, Level 1,   64 KB, Assoc   2, LineSize  64
--**----  Unified Cache       2, Level 2,    2 MB, Assoc  16, LineSize  64
---*----  Data Cache          3, Level 1,   16 KB, Assoc   4, LineSize  64
----*---  Data Cache          4, Level 1,   16 KB, Assoc   4, LineSize  64
----**--  Instruction Cache   2, Level 1,   64 KB, Assoc   2, LineSize  64
----**--  Unified Cache       3, Level 2,    2 MB, Assoc  16, LineSize  64
-----*--  Data Cache          5, Level 1,   16 KB, Assoc   4, LineSize  64
------*-  Data Cache          6, Level 1,   16 KB, Assoc   4, LineSize  64
------**  Instruction Cache   3, Level 1,   64 KB, Assoc   2, LineSize  64
------**  Unified Cache       4, Level 2,    2 MB, Assoc  16, LineSize  64
-------*  Data Cache          7, Level 1,   16 KB, Assoc   4, LineSize  64

Logical Processor to Group Map:
********  Group 0
```

Comment: For these kind of feature just having a CPU which supports them is not enough. We also need support from other parts such as the BIOS. These often have an 'enable/disable virtualisation' option. Can you check for that?

Comment: It might be called " "Secure Virtual Machine Mode"

Comment: Enable Virtualization in your BIOS

Comment: @Scorpion99 I checked out bios but could not find any option to enable or disable it. Can you please point out what should I be looking for ?

Comment: It is called as Hennes already said : Secure Virtual Machine Mode

Comment: Secure Virtual Machine Mode (SVM) is already enabled in BIOS. I also updated BIOS with the latest one.

Answer (score 1):

That processor specifically supports AMD-V according to its specs, but your output from Coreinfo above shows that it does not.

Since you've already checked the virtualization options in your BIOS, try flashing your BIOS to a newer version.  I checked ASUS's web site and it says that motherboard only supports the FX-8120 for BIOS revision 0801 or later.  Check what revision you have.  Your current BIOS may not fully support that processor model.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the solution and it is somewhat strange.

as suggested by Hennes in comment the option "Secure Virtual Machine Mode" has to be worked out. The real catch here was I had to disable that option. With secure virtual machine mode, this bios allows only one CPU to be allocated for virtual machine. I could allocate more CPU after disabling the option.

I am not sure if it is the correct approach to deal with it. It has however enable the slider and I can allocate more CPU but I am not sure if it is proper way. Suggestions / more details on this will be very helpful to me as well as others also.